# Laravel Validator "in:" not seeing first element

Tags: laravel, validation

I have the following ruleset.  The "in:" rules will fail with not found if the first element in the array is entered in the input field.  However if 2nd or subsequent elements are selected then the rule fires ok.  Has anyone else had this issue?  I am using "Laravel 7"

```
"title": "required|min:2|max:50|regex:/^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z ]+$/u",
"target_start_date": "required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:today",
"target_finish_date": "required|date_format:Y-m-d|after_or_equal:target_start_date",
"genre": "required|in:[adventure,action,biographical,contemporary,crime,thriller,mystery,fantasy,historical,horror,medical,myths,political,romance,sci_fi,war]",
"visibility": "required|in:[public,friends,public]",
"owner_starts": "required|in:[yes,no,sequence,random]",
"owner_finishes": "required|in:[yes,no,sequence,random]"
```

Comment: I think this would have just worked if you removed the `[` and `]` around your values, like `in:adventure,action,biographical,contemporary,crime,thriller,mystery,fantasy,historical,horror,medical,myths,political,romance,sci_fi,war`. This is the older syntax for constructing rules, but is still valid.

Comment: _This is the older syntax for constructing rules, but is still valid._ @TimLewis Is it? As I’ve been using Laravel since the 4.0 beta, and I’ve never come across that syntax for specifying `in` values.

Comment: @MartinBean Yup! I'm looking at one of my Laravel 6.x projects, and this is how I use the  `in` rule: `'model_id' => 'required|in:' . $validModels->pluck('id')->implode(','),`, which equates to `'model_id' => 'required|in:1,2,3'`, and it works just fine :) I've been using that since Laravel 4.2-ish: https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/validation#rule-in

Comment: @TimLewis Yeah, you can specify a comma-delimited string. I was more on about the wrapping of the values in the square brackets, i.e. `in:[values,here]`

Comment: @MartinBean Oh that, no, that's not valid. It would literally be looking for `[values`, and `here]` as valid options, instead of `values` and `here` :P That's why it's "not seeing first element". `'[adventure'` is not the same as `'adventure'` lol Sorry, I didn't mean the `[` and `]` is valid, which I see now is how my comment reads.

Comment: Thanks guys the braces [ ] were causing the problems. Very much appreciate the fast help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"owner_finishes": "required|in:[yes,no,sequence,random]"
```

Should be:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

 'owner_finishes' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['yes', 'no', 'sequence', 'random']),
    ],
```

As the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-in) says:

> Since this rule often requires you to implode an array, the Rule::in method may be used to fluently construct the rule:

Answer (score 3):

That’s not how you specify values for the `in` rule; you just specify the options as comma-delimited strings. For example:

```php
'visibility' => ['required', 'in:public,friends'],
```

(I’ve also used the “array” syntax for specifying rules, as it makes each individual validation rule easier to see rather than a long string full of `|` characters.)

If the available options are stored as an array elsewhere in your application, such as a repository or a configuration file, then you can pass that array of options directly to the “fluent” rule builder as per Charlie’s answer:

```php
'genre' => [
    'required',
    Rule::in($genres),
],
```

Be sure to import `Illuminate\Validation\Rule` if you want to use this approach.

Comment: Worth noting this is the string syntax. You also have the class validator syntax which I specified in my answer bellow